# Plant data is not passing in MM02

Tags: hook, abap, sap-erp

I am updating a custom table based on plant in MM02 using the user exit EXIT_SAPLMGMU_001. The problem is when i am not passing through Plant data\ stor.1 tab plant data is not passing to the exit i am using.

I need to update the custom table even when basic data is changed without changing plant. please suggest me how to achieve this.

Comment: are you sure about that? I just put a break point right before the exit call and even if I just enter the material general data and save without changing anything the exit is still executed.

Comment: yeah..its not passing wmarc-werks

Comment: of course it isn't. If you don't supply a plant when entering the editing mode, the exit won't be able to supply the plant to the exit. There could be any number of plants for that material, so the program can't just choose any one of them. If you want to know which plants the material was created for, read table MARC from within the exit. If wmarc is initial, you know the user didn't change MARC values. And also prepare for cases where there is NO plant at all, for instance when you create a new material.

Comment: or do you mean it isn't passing plant data although you entered a plant but didn't change any plant data? That would be more difficult. You could try GET PARAMETER ID to get the last plant entered. The parameter id for the plant is WRK.

Answer (score 0):

You should better imagine SAP [organizational structure](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/75/ee0a9555c811d189900000e8322d00/content.htm?frameset=/en/75/ee0a9555c811d189900000e8322d00/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/75/ee1fa755c811d189900000e8322d00/plain.htm&node_id=5&show_children=false) to answer your own questuion. 
Company codes are subdivided into plants, plants can be assigned to one or more [purchasing](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/ff/515a2849d811d182b80000e829fbfe/content.htm?frameset=/en/ff/515a4249d811d182b80000e829fbfe/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/ff/516a6749d811d182b80000e829fbfe/plain.htm&node_id=7) or [sales organization](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/ff/515a4249d811d182b80000e829fbfe/content.htm?frameset=/en/ff/515a2849d811d182b80000e829fbfe/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/ff/516a6749d811d182b80000e829fbfe/plain.htm&node_id=8). So plant division makes sense only while editing material's sales or purchasing master data. 
As Dirk fairly said, your plant details just **shouldn't** be normally passed to your user-exit in case you don't open sales or purchasing views in MM02. And if you do, MARC-WERKS is perfectly populated